# Rails 4.2.4 with RVM 1.26.11 Environment Variable [ Not Set / Unable To Read ]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

I am trying to use the RVM `.ruby-env` file to set an environment variable to hold the database password for my project. When I then go to create the database via the `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create` command I get an error specifying that the password isn't set: `"password"=>nil}`.

`.ruby-env` is located in the root directory of my rails project, and to all accounts [as per the RVM website](https://rvm.io/workflow/projects):

> This variable will be set when entering the project directory and reverted to its previous value when exiting the project directory.

---

### `.ruby-env` contents:

`VT_DATABASE_PASSWORD=testing1234`

### `config/database.yml` contents:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  host: localhost

production:
  <<: *default
  database: vagrant_test_production
  username: lotus
  password: <%= ENV['VT_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

### Command and error:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/vagrant_test$ RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:655:in `initialize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:655:in `new'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:655:in `connect'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each_current_configuration'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "pool"=>5, "host"=>"localhost", "database"=>"vagrant_test_production", "username"=>"lotus", "password"=>nil}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just having problems with

```
ENV['VT_DATABASE_PASSWORD']
```

the value is just nil (null)

try to add these lines to your config/secrets.yml

```
production:
  VT_DATABASE_PASSWORD: "your db password"
```

Otherwise you can just try to add the password to the database.yml (that file is not suppose to be in any repository so it's not public